# MongoDB returns Undefined when searching for a user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running a node.js app as a backend for an android app (which is why it is a post method, not a get) that is searching for a user with this code:

```
router.route('/exists').post((req, res) => {
    User.find({ UserName: req.body.username })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ status: 404 })
            }
            else {
                console.log(user._id)
                res.status(200).json({ _id: user._id })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
})
```

and returns as a json.

This code is returning undefined. I am 100% sure that MongoDB has record of my user. The other methods in the same file work perfectly fine. I feel like I am missing something easy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a bit more info on what "returning undefined" means? As in, what did console.log show, and what did the client side show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer for all that have the same type of issue and end up here.

According to this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

`find()` returns a list. Node was not expecting a list. Changing it to `findOne()` worked.